# Create sendmail/dovecot email alias username for logging in CENTOS LINUX

Tags: sendmail, dovecot, mta

I currently use sendmail and dovecot as a email server
each user is also a username on the centos linux user accounts

/etc/mail/virtusertable will contain (john is an example user)

```
john@example.com  john
```

however how can  john login using john@example.com  with dovecot/sendmail ?

I dont use postfix as a MTA just sendmail and dovecot for IMAP